# Filebeat not streaming to kafka due to error %!s(int32=1)]]/%!d(MISSING) abandoning broker %!d(MISSING)

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, filebeat

I have my filebeat prospector with config of

```
         prospectors:
            - type: log
              paths: /var/log/nginx/*error*.log
              enabled: true
              fields:
                source_type: topic-secerror-nginx
        output.kafka:
           hosts: ["kafkahost:kafkaport"]
           topic: "%{[fields][source_type]}"
```

I am getting strange errors in filebeat as give below

```
        2019-11-20T10:25:08.167Z    INFO    kafka/log.go:36 producer/broker/[[3 %!d(string=topic-secerror-nginx) 2]] state change to [open] on %!s(MISSING)/%!d(MISSING)

        2019-11-20T10:25:08.167Z    INFO    kafka/log.go:36 producer/leader/[[topic-secerror-nginx %!s(int32=2) %!s(int=3)]]/%!d(MISSING) state change to [flushing-%!d(MISSING)]

        2019-11-20T10:25:08.167Z    INFO    kafka/log.go:36 producer/leader/[[topic-secerror-nginx %!s(int32=2)]]/%!d(MISSING) state change to [normal]
```

The kafka is not consuming any infor sent from filebeat.

When I set it to debug mode, I have the error as

```
    %!s(int32=1)]]/%!d(MISSING) abandoning broker %!d(MISSING)
```

Comment: Have you enabled Kafka module? `filebeat modules enable kafka`

Answer (score 0):

i got this resolved. The issue was to do with firewall blocked between filebeat and kafka.
When filebeat logging was set to debug, got additional information pertaining to TCP connection refused.